# gradle generated file from a task not available in final jar

Tags: gradle, jar, libgdx

I have set up some tasks compiling a libGdx project in Android Studio. What I want is, that a dynamic file "version.txt" is created in the assets folder. This file must be available in the final jar-output.

Here is how I did the setup:

libGdx provides me with a `dist` task.
I created two tasks on top of that: `buildDebugVersion` and `buildReleaseVersion`.

Both shall create a `version.txt`, one containing debug information and the other no debug info.

#### libGdx' original dist task

```
task dist(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
    //processResources.dependsOn tasks.updateVersionFileRelease
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar
}
```

#### my debug/release tasks

```
task createDebugVersion  {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    doFirst {
        modifyVersionFile(1)
    }
}

task createReleaseVersion  {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    doFirst {
        modifyVersionFile(0)
    }
}
```

#### task dependencies

To put that all in the right running order, I created

```
createDebugVersion.finalizedBy(tasks.dist)
createReleaseVersion.finalizedBy(tasks.dist)
dist.mustRunAfter(tasks.createDebugVersion, tasks.createReleaseVersion)
```

My expectation was:

- createdebug/release runs and creates the file
- **THEN** dist runs

This seems to happen, when I look at the output. You can see, what file is generated:

Here is the output when I run it:

```
> Task :desktop:createReleaseVersion
Generated version file is:
--------------------------
Version=0.1.113
BuildDate=2020-04-24
--------------------------

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
10 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

...but when I run the program, I see this version information:

[image]

The file contained in the jar is alway *1 or 2 versions behind*, as if it would've been taken out of some cache folder.

What scares me is the question: How many of the other assets are now 1 or 2 versions behind, too?
From where does gradle take this file?

I was not able to find it out so far.

#### what I already tried

I run this through a `.cmd` script. Before starting the gradle task, I already delete all build folders (and tested it, everything is removed before the build starts)

(the variable %TASK% contains either `createDebugVersion` or `createReleaseVersion`)

```
ECHO Forcing resources rebuild
RD /S /Q .\desktop\build
RD /S /Q .\android\build

ECHO Compiling distribution version of %GAMENAME%...
CALL gradlew desktop:clean desktop:build %TASK% --rerun-tasks
```

But still, out of some "ghost-galaxy-space", a file that is two builds old is taken from somewhere and put into the jar...

Any help *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: Additional info: I now also delete the .gradle folder. This did not solve the problem.
But I found something out:
The output lands in desktop/build/libs  -> the version file contained there is one number behind the file I just generated!
From where does gradle take this file?

the entire /build folder has been deleted before the build starts, so it must be copied fresh from an unknown source... what source could that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out - maybe it helps others if they run into a similar issue.

#### The error was here:

```
CALL gradlew desktop:clean desktop:build %TASK% --rerun-tasks
```

If you look closely, you see FIRST `desktop:clean` runs, THEN `desktop:build runs`, which causes a full-rebuild due to the deleted caches and build folders, and THEN my `%TASK%` runs - as **third** in order!

So, my task runs *after* the build. Even when I put up the build chain with

```
createDebugVersion.finalizedBy(tasks.dist)
createReleaseVersion.finalizedBy(tasks.dist)
```

this all only runs *after* the build is already done. And the `dist` task has no `clean` in this build chain so it uses the output of the build generated by the second parameter of my `gradlew` call!

#### The solution

I simply changed how I run `gradlew`:

my command script now calls

```
call gradlew desktop:clean %TASK% --rerun-tasks
```

so a `clean` is still forced, but the `build` only happens as a reaction from `dist` because it can't find any binaries, so it has to build them right now.
And *then* the build finally runs *after* my file has been written to the assets folder.

Hope this helps someone some day!
cheers, gris